Smooth Transfered Normals
The shading on my character's face looks generally good, but the shadow below the jaw looks terrible. I'm making a game model, and it's extremely important for me to keep the polygon count low. I want to achieve the result on the left screenshot. On the right is what I have.

I use DataTransfer with the "Projected Face Interpolated" method to move custom normals from the low poly model to the detailed head. That's where these artifacts come from, but this method of creating custom normals is too convenient for me to just give it up.

Do you have any tricky options in mind to smooth out the existing shading? Shade smooth is already enabled.

You can't use standard phong interpolation between vertices, for the effect you're going for, you need to define some focal point, somewhere around the eyebrow, and transition the normal based on distance from it. Or bake to a texture.

I suggest to display the split normals to be able to see what you're working with. You can do this from the Mesh Edit Mode Overlays (only accessible while in Edit Mode).

Then, I suggest to select the vertices that have normals issues and try the operators under Mesh > Normals.  I think Smooth Vectors or Reset Vectors may be what you're looking for. You can also try rotating normals manually using the Rotate... operator under the same menu (shortcut R > N > X, Y, or Z for constrained rotation).

I was able to achieve a favorable result.
To summarize, I did three things.


I added topology in the place where there should be a clear separation between highlighting and shadowing.



I changed the low poly mesh experimentally until everything looked a little better. In the end, a well-working option was an elongated jaw. (The effectiveness of this point is affected by point 3)



I selected the face and its side parts in a vertex group. And added a new DataTransfer (hereinafter DT) to the main DT, the task of which was to rotate all the normals of the verteses of this vertex group out of the ped. Only after this is the DT applied, which transfers the general normals of the head. This creates the necessary contrast between the lower and side sides of the jaw (sry for the tautology).


I took into account all the answers. Thank you very much for your help (●'◡'●)
